# Flutter Firebase MultiFactor not working on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented MultiFactor authentication in my flutter app, where I'm using FireBase for my authenticator. Everything works great on Android and it also works great on IOS on an emulator and also if I deploy a debug version to a physical IOS device, it works great.

The flow is the user logs in with username/password, I detect if I get a multifactor error, and if yes, I use a showDialog method to have them enter the SMS code , which I then use to authenticate them. This is how the documentation shows it.

However, In a release version on IOS, it is not working...the dialog box to show user to enter the sms code never appears.  and I can't seem to find a way to figure out why. In my code, I have a try/catch around the code and I use FlutterToast to output an error if it occurs, but even this does not show. When I click sign-in, nothing appears to happen. It works in debug mode and I've checked the console to see if any other errors show that would stop it in release mode, but no errors appear.

Below is my login code that is being invoked.
I am using Flutter 3.10.6. and firebase_auth: ^4.1.1

Any ideas why this is not working in release mode in IOS and how I might fix?

```
static Future<void> Login(String email, String password,
      Function loadUserData, Function getSmsCode, BuildContext ctx) async {
    final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      await loadUserData();
    } on FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException catch (e) {
      final firstHint = e.resolver.hints.first;

      if (firstHint is! PhoneMultiFactorInfo) {
        return;
      }

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        multiFactorSession: e.resolver.session,
        multiFactorInfo: firstHint,
        verificationCompleted: (_) {},
        verificationFailed: (_) {},
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
          // See `firebase_auth` example app for a method of retrieving user's sms code:
          // https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/auth.dart#L591

          final smsCode = await getSmsCode(ctx);

          if (smsCode != null) {
            // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
            final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: verificationId,
              smsCode: smsCode,
            );

            try {
              await e.resolver.resolveSignIn(
                PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.getAssertion(
                  credential,
                ),
              );
              await loadUserData();
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              print('auth fail...');
              print(e.message);
            }
          }
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {},
      );
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.toString().contains('firebase_auth')) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: error.toString().replaceAll('firebase_auth/', ''));
      } else {
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```